# On the Relationship Between Two Linear Transformations of a Finite-Dimensional Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ and $(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n)$ be two bases of a $k$-vector space $V$ with two linear transformations $B : V \to V$ and $C : V \to V$ defined by
> $$B a_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_{ij} a_i \text{ and } C b_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_{ij} b_i.$$ We want to find the connection between $B$ and $C.$

Consider the transformation matrix $$P = \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1n} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ p_{n1} & p_{n2} & \cdots & p_{nn} \end{pmatrix},$$ and denote the bases by $X = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ and $Y = \{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n\}.$ Is it true that $B(C(Y)) = P*(C(Y))$ and also $C(B(X)) = P*(B(X))?$

Are these necessary to solve this exercise, or does it need something more?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What are the $(a_{ij})$?

Comment: I corrected this